# Checking status2 value in sybase

Tags: sybase, offline, sap-ase

I am fetching status2 value in sybase using the following query

```
select name, status, status2 FROM sysdatabases
```

After fetching the status2 value I am converting it into 16 bit binary value and checking the 4th and 5th bit to check if the database is offline. 
The problem arises when a database has **abort tran on log full** set as true and the value of status2 is -32767. This sets all the bits to 1. Is the method that I have followed to check if a database is offline correct?

I am using the below doc for reference
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1550/html/tables/X42615.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the below response in SAP community

> 1> create database test 2> go CREATE DATABASE: allocating 1536 logical
>   pages (3.0 megabytes) on disk 'master' (1536 logical pages requested).
>   Database 'test' is now online.
>
> 1> select convert(binary(2), status2), status2 from sysdatabases where
>   name = "test" 2> go status2
>   ------ ------- 0x8000 -32768
>
> (1 row affected) 1> sp_dboption test, 'abort tran', true 2> go
>   Database option 'abort tran on log full' turned ON for database
>   'test'. Running CHECKPOINT on database 'test' for option 'abort tran
>   on log full' to take effect. (return status = 0) 1> select
>   convert(binary(2), status2), status2 from sysdatabases where name =
>   "test" 2> go status2
>   ------ ------- 0x8001 -32767
>
> (1 row affected)
>
> To test whether either "offline" bit was on, I would check if (status2
>   & 48 > 0 )